# Open another screen React-navigation 3.. flatlist

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

i got error when i'm trying to navigate to another screen by clicking on TouchableOpacity.. "you should render one navigator explicitly in your app, and other navigator should be rendered by including them in that navigator."
I'm using react-navigation 3 and here is are my 4 components:

this is the main component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';
import {createBottomTabNavigator , createNavigationContainer} from 'react-navigation'
import Home from './Compnents/Home';
import CreatePost from './Compnents/CreatePost';
import Notifications from './Compnents/Notifications';

 export class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>          
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const NavigationBar = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Home:{ screen : Home , 
  navigationOptions:{
    tabBarLabel:'home',
  }},
  Notifications:{screen : Notifications,
    navigationOptions:{
      tabBarLabel: 'notifi',
    }},
    CreatePost : {screen :CreatePost , 
    navigationOptions:{
      tabBarLabel: 'createpost',
    } },

});
export default createNavigationContainer(NavigationBar);....
```

the second one which includes the NotificationList component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, } from 'react-native';
import NotificationsList from './NotificationsList';

export default class Notifications extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <View  style={styles.container} >
      <Text style={styles.HomeText}> AAA </Text>
                           <NotificationsList />   
      </View>
    );
  }
}...
```

and finally the 3rd one, which when i click on item i got the error

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { FlatList } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import {createStackNavigator , createNavigationContainer,} from 'react-navigation';
import DonationRoom from './DonationRoom';

 const Room =createStackNavigator({
   DonationRoom : DonationRoom
 })

export default createNavigationContainer ( Room);
class NotificationsList extends React.Component {

  ItemClickListener(){

    navigate('DonationRoom');
  }

  render() {

    return (   
      <View  style={styles.container} >

            <FlatList
            data={[
                {timestamp : '2018/12/26' , comment : 'aaaaa'}  ,
                {timestamp : '2018/12/26' , comment : 'aaaaaaa'},
            ]}
            renderItem={({item})=>
            <TouchableOpacity  style={styles.item} 
            onPress={() => this.ItemClickListener()}>
                <View style={{flexDirection : 'row-reverse'}}>
                      <Text > {item.timestamp} </Text>
                    </View>
                    <Text style={{marginTop : 10 , margin:3}}> {item.comment} 
    </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
        }
            />
      </View>
    );
  } 
}...
```

to open this page:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';

export default class DonationRoom extends React.Component {

  render() {

    return (
      <View  style={styles.container} >
      <Text style={styles.HomeText}>aaa </Text>
         <Text > Donaiton Room </Text>

      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: basically you should include all your navigation routes in one file, so instead of explicitly making a separate `StackNavigator`, just put it in your main/root file with the `BottomTabNavigator`. Then in your `TouchableOpacity` just do `this.props.navigation.navigate('DonationRoom')`

Comment: can you specifically what adjustments i have to do in this code please :(?.. cause i didn't understand well D:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution but still think it's not the proper way but it works:

in the second component "Notificatins" all I've to do create the StackNavigator in,And pass the Navigation prop to the 3rd component "NotificationsList", so to gonna be like this:

```
class Notifications extends React.Component {

  render() {   
    return (
      <View  style={styles.container} >
      <Text style={styles.HomeText}> aaa</Text>

               <NotificationsList navigation={this.props.navigation}/>

      </View>
    );
  }
}
export default  StackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Notifications : {screen: Notifications , 
    navigationOptions:{
      header : null
    }},
  DonationRoom :{screen : DonationRoom ,
   navigationOptions:{
      title : 'more'
   }},
});
```

then on 3rd component I did add  `this.props.navigation.navigate('DonationRoom');`  to the  `ItemClickListener()` Function.

And that's it, I hope there is a better or an appropriate solution than this one Thnx..